Eth and Ethbar derivatives in Newman-Penrose (NP) formalism
Why does the following vanishes in Newman-Penrose (NP) formalism?
$$ \int d^2 \Omega \eth F_{-1}, $$
where $F_{-1}$ is a quantity of spin weight $-1$ and $\eth$ is the spin raising operator? It is not obvious that this is a boundary term. If $F$ has $l>1$ harmonics, would it still vanish?
